# i don't know __iter__ in python,who can give me a good code example

Tags: python, iterator

my code run wrong

```
class a(object):
    def __iter(self):
        return 33
b={'a':'aaa','b':'bbb'}
c=a()
print b.itervalues()
print c.itervalues()
```

Please try to use the code, rather than text, because my English is not very good, thank you

Answer (score 17, accepted):

a. Spell it right: **not**

```
   def __iter(self):
```

but:

```
   def __iter__(self):
```

with `__` before **and** after `iter`.

b. Make the body right: **not**

```
return 33
```

but:

```
yield 33
```

or
    return iter([33])

If you `return` a value from `__iter__`, return an iterator (an *iterable*, as in `return [33]`, is almost as good but not quite...); or else, `yield` 1+ values, making `__iter__` into a generator function (so it intrinsically returns a generator iterator).

c. Call it right: **not**

```
a().itervalues()
```

but, e.g.:

```
for x in a(): print x
```

or

```
print list(a())
```

`itervalues` is a method of dict, and has nothing to do with `__iter__`.

If you fix all three (!) mistakes, the code works better;-).

Comment: But if he's just returning (yielding) 33, is that really an *iterator*?

Comment: Well, if you **yield** 33, then yes, then the method becomes a generator expression, that yields an iterator. When you return [33], well, a list is certainly iterable, so it works too.

Comment: @Goose and @Shylent, yep: `yield 33` makes `__iter__` a generator function (**not** generator _expression_ -- that's a different construct;-), so it returns a generator, which is an iterator; `return [33]` returns an iterable but not an iterator, so that's slightly imperfect -- editing answer to fix that quibble!-)

Comment: Oh, you are of course right about generator **function** vs generator **expression**, don't know what I've been thinking while writing that.

Answer (score 5):

A few things about your code:

1. `__iter` should be `__iter__`
2. You're returning '33' in the `__iter__` function. You should actually be returning an *iterator object*. An iterator is an object which keeps returning different values when it's `next()` function is called (maybe a sequence of values like [0,1,2,3 etc]).

Here's a working example of an iterator:

```
class a(object):
    def __init__(self,x=10):
        self.x = x
    def __iter__(self):
        return self
    def next(self):
        if self.x > 0:
            self.x-=1
            return self.x
        else:
            raise StopIteration

c=a()

for x in c:
    print x
```

Any object of class `a` is an iterator object. Calling the `__iter__` function is supposed to return the iterator, so it returns **itself** – as you can see, the a class has a `next()` function, so this is an iterator object.

When the next function is called, it keeps return consecutive values until it hits zero, and then it sends the `StopIteration` exception, which (appropriately) stops the iteration.

If this seems a little hazy, I would suggest experimenting with the code and then checking out the documentation here: http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html

Answer (score 1):

Here is a code example that implements the xrange builtin:

```
class my_xrange(object):
    def __init__(self, start, end, skip=1):
        self.curval = int(start)
        self.lastval = int(end)
        self.skip = int(skip)
        assert(int(skip) != 0)

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def next(self):
        if (self.skip > 0) and (self.curval >= self.lastval):
            raise StopIteration()
        elif (self.skip < 0) and (self.curval <= self.lastval):
            raise StopIteration()
        else:
            oldval = self.curval
            self.curval += self.skip
            return oldval

for i in my_xrange(0, 10):
    print i
```

Comment: That tells Python to throw an exception if skip is 0.  If skip is 0 the iterator will never terminate and will always print out the same value.

Comment: It is not necessary and is only there to make the class safer to use.  It can be removed without harm.

Answer (score 0):

You are using this language feature incorrectly.

http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#iterator-types

This above link will explain what the function should be used for.

You can try to see documentation in your native language here:  http://wiki.python.org/moin/Languages