# Looping over Iterator

Tags: python, python-3.x, iterator

Sorry if this is a silly question, but I could not make my mind up how it could work.

I defined an iterator which has a structure like that (it is a bit more complicated, but the model will do the job):

```
class MyIterator ():

    def __init__(self):
        print ('nothing happening here')

    def __iter__ (self):
        self.a_list=[x for x in range (10)]
        for y in a_list:
            print(y)


    def __next__ (self):
        self.a_list = [x+1 for x in self.a_list]
        for y in a_list:
            print (y)
```

But how can I loop over it? Do I always have to call the methods manually? Or am I simply using the wrong tool?

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/a/1956648/1229455.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I just realised the example given by me does not really describe it well. I will try to edit it.

Comment: @Sven : How did you do the syntax highlighting?

Comment: Normally, the syntax highlighting happens automatically.  See also [Syntax highlighting language hints](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/981/syntax-highlighting-language-hints) on Meta.

Answer (score 7):

One of the problems is that you are mixing two concepts:  And
*iterable* defines an `__iter__()` method that returns an *iterator*,
but no `__next__()` method.  An *iterator* in turn defines a
`__next__()` method, and a trivial `__iter__()` implementation that
returns `self`.  Something like this:

```py
class Iterable(object):
    def __iter__(self):
        return Iterator()

class Iterator(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.i = 0
    def __iter__(self):
        return self
    def __next__(self):
        result = self.i
        self.i += 1
        return result
```

An alternative is to define the `__iter__()` method of the iterable as a *generator function*:

```py
class Iterable(object):
    def __iter__(self):
        i = 0
        while True:
            yield i
            i += 1
```

Comment: Thanks! I was not really aware of that difference! So the __next__ method has always to return a value? Because what I am trying to do is print out the a certain value per coordinate (which are stored in a dict) with the \033[ syntax. I do not really now how to return the resulting values, as they should all be returned at once (they are some hundred). I uploaded the full code (which is really only a concept so far), as I can not really describe the problem with my poor english http://pastebin.com/FaDrTCYz. If you have some spare energy I would be very grateful.

Comment: @glglgl The thing is, afterwards the values are processed and then the whole bunch of values should be returned again, but only if asked for and theoretically infinitly expandable. I thought this is quite what iterators could do, or is there something similar?

Comment: @kyril: Iterators should usually be defined for some kind of container, and should be used to ierate over these containers.  This means they enable e.g. the  `for x in Iterable` syntax.  They are not meant to print anything.

Comment: @SvenMarnach Okay thanks, I'll look for some other technique!