# Python Linked List Append

Tags: python, linked-list, append

I made an append method for an UnorderedList() class that works fine in my IDLE window but when its assigned to the University's test of:

```
my_list = UnorderedList()
my_list.append(13)
for num in my_list: 
    print(num, end=" ")
print()
```

it returns an error: `AttributeError: Nonetype object has no attribute 'getNext'`.

Here is the append method:

```
def append(self,item):
    current = self.head
    while current.getNext() != None:
        current = current.getNext()
    current.setNext(Node(item))
```

Here is the rest of my classes and code:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self,initdata):
        self.data = initdata
        self.next = None

    def getData(self):
        return self.data

    def getNext(self):
        return self.next

    def setData(self,newdata):
        self.data = newdata

    def setNext(self,newnext):
        self.next = newnext

class UnorderedList:

    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None
        self.count = 0

    def append(self,item):
        current = self.head
        while current.getNext() != None:
            current = current.getNext()
        current.setNext(Node(item))
```

Why is the test returning that error and how I can fix my append method?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is here in the append method:

```
def append(self,item):
    current = self.head
    while current.getNext() != None:
        current = current.getNext()
    current.setNext(Node(item))
```

In the first iteration, the value of `current` is `self.head`, which is set to `None` initially, and you don't check for it.

So instead, alter this and introduce checks for this condition ad below:

```
def append(self,item):
    current = self.head
    if current:
        while current.getNext() != None:
            current = current.getNext()
        current.setNext(Node(item))
    else:
        self.head = Node(item)
```

PS: you are also using a variable `self.count`, which you are not updating. You might want to update the same as well.

Comment: I think the append function works now but It is now returning: Error: "UnorderedList" object is not iterable. How do I make my list iterable?

Comment: @Newbie it wasn't an iterable in the first place, the `for` loop wouldn't work in its current form. You can define a custom [`__iter__`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1956623/1860929) method to fix that. Anyway, that would be a separate question, so you can ask a new one regarding your implementation about the same.

Comment: Ok I will have to research how to do that. Thank you

Comment: @Newbie Just edited my last comment. Also, if that helped, don't forget to [accept and upvote](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) :)

Comment: I have tried making an __iter__ method but the while loop does not end. Any help? I can only post a question in 90 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

your append method works fine but it traverses the list until it finds the last node - which makes it O(n). If you keep track of the last node, you can make an append which is O(1):

```
def append_O1(self, item):
        temp = Node(item)
        last = self.tail
        last.setnext(temp)
        self.tail = temp
        self.length += 1
```

To enable this your list class constructor should be:

```
class unorderedList:
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None
        self.tail = None
        self.length = 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding little more elaborated append methods

Method to insert at the beginning

```
def inserAtBeginning(self, item):
    newNode = Node(item)
    newNode.setdata(item)
    if self.listLength() == 0:
        self.head = newNode
    else:
        newNode.setnext(self.head)
        self.head = newNode
```

Method to insert at the end

```
def insertAtEnd(self, item):
    newNode = Node(item)
    newNode.setdata(item)
    current = self.head
    while current.getnext() != None:
        current = current.getnext()
    current.setnext(newNode)
```

Method to insert at the  specified position

```
def insertAtPos(self, pos, item):
    if pos > self.listLength() or pos < 0:
        return None
    if pos == 0:
        self.inserAtBeginning(item)
    else:
        if pos == self.listLength():
            self.insertAtEnd(item)
        else:
            newNode = Node(item)
            newNode.setdata(item)
            current = self.head
            count = 0
            while count < pos - 1:
                count += 1
                current = current.getnext()
            newNode.setnext(current.getnext())
            current.setnext(newNode)
```

Answer (score 1):

This O(n) implementation should work for an empty list too :

```
def append(self,item):
    current = self.head
    if current == None:
        self.head = Node(item)
    else:
        while current.getNext() != None:
            current = current.getNext()

        current.setNext(Node(item))
```